# Where to put periodic background sync in Next.js PWA

Tags: next.js, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a **Next.js** progressive web app (PWA). I'm trying to use a [periodic background sync](https://felixgerschau.com/periodic-background-sync-explained/) in this PWA. To register such a periodic background sync process I have to use a registration code like this:

```
// Check if service workers are supported
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
  // Check if periodicSync is supported
  if ('periodicSync' in registration) {
    // Request permission
    const status = await navigator.permissions.query({
      name: 'periodic-background-sync',
    });
    if (status.state === 'granted') {
      try {
        // Register new sync every 24 hours
        await registration.periodicSync.register('news', {
          minInterval: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 day
        });
        console.log('Periodic background sync registered!');
      } catch(e) {
        console.error(`Periodic background sync failed:\n${e}`);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Now my question is:** where do I have to put this code?

I see 2 options where to trigger this code:

1. **Inside _app.js:** The code gets executed on each page switch. Does this make sense? Probably not.
2. **On a click handler:** This requires manuel interaction to execute the code once. The problem I see is that I can't register automatically without user interaction.

Ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome and other Chromium-based browsers, [Periodic Background Sync](https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/) is only available in progressive web apps that have gone through the install flow. Assuming it's been installed, though, no further permission prompts are needed. So, at least in its current implementation, you don't have to worry about spamming a user with permission prompts if you attempt to register it or query for the state on page load.

In a recent side project that I worked on, I did something similar to the first approach, where I just [attempted the registration](https://github.com/jeffposnick/yt-playlist-notifier/blob/d038e795d2e876b178884212cabd5430971e28bb/src/lib/sw-helpers.ts#L26-L37) on each page load.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Let's wait till someone maybe posts a solution how not to register on each page load. But maybe this solution is good enough.